# Selenium not detecting Sub menu object in small browser window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate testing for a web application that has responsive/adaptive design.

When a user uses a full screen browser, a different display is shown based on the screen display dimensions.

I've fully automated the application tests using the full screen browser, but when I attempt to test using the mobile browser, the navigation menu is displayed differently. In a smaller window, the nav menu must be clicked to expand it, then the sub-menu object can be selected. I tried to use both an emulator, a physical device, and a normal window just sized down, all with no luck.

I can expand the main menu with no issues, however, Selenium cannot seem to detect the sub-menu objects, no matter what I try. I've tried doing an actions builder with no results. I continue to get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"partial link text","selector":"spotlight"}
```

For an example of a similar menu to what I am experiencing difficulties with, go to cleanandclear.com and make your window size smaller than full screen.

The code I would EXPECT to work is:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("touch-menu")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Spotlight")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Spotlight"));//u can use xpath or cssselector or id here.

//this line will scroll down to make element visible
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

//don't use this kind of wait, use explicit wait
Thread.sleep(1000);

//use this explicit wait.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ur selector of that animated element")));//u can use by  id or xpath here also. 

elem.click();

//u can also use this function to make the element visible
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
elem.click();
```

Comment: This solves it - but not for the reason I originally thought. Turns out that the issue was solved because of your line: Thread.sleep(1000);

The navigation menu opens a sub menu, but on the page I am testing it displays a short expanding animation when it does it. This was throwing off the timing of the script, the line to click the object was happening prior to it being fully displayed.

So, thank you! It was much simpler than I thought.

Comment: in that case, its better to use explicit wait ... i already added this in my updated answer..... and would be happy if u accept this by click on tick mark....:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , in smaller screen *height of my dropdown was greater than the browser window height* so selenium webdriver was not able to find the elements . So I minimized the html to twice/thrice  which fits the browser .

To minimize html you may use this code :

```
WebElement html = seleniumHelper.getDriver().findElement(By.tagName("html"));
html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

This solved my issue .